# Setting a Javascript Private Variable with the same name as a Function Parameter?

Tags: javascript, private, javascript-objects

```
function Foo() {
    var myPrivateBool = false,
        myOtherVar;
    this.bar = function(myOtherVar) {
        myPrivateBool = true;
        myOtherVar = myOtherVar; // ?????????????????
    };
}
```

How can I set the private variable myOtherVar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the parameter a different name:

```
    function Foo() {
        var myPrivateBool = false,
            myOtherVar;
        this.bar = function( param ) {
            myPrivateBool = true;
            myOtherVar = param;
        };
        this.baz = function() {
            alert( myOtherVar );
        };
    }


var inst = new Foo;

inst.bar( "new value" );

inst.baz();  // alerts the value of the variable "myOtherVar"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/efqVW/

---

Or create a private function to set the value if you prefer.

```
function Foo() {
    var myPrivateBool = false,
        myOtherVar;
    function setMyOtherVar( v ) {
        myOtherVar = v;
    }
    this.bar = function(myOtherVar) {
        myPrivateBool = true;
        setMyOtherVar( myOtherVar );
    };
    this.baz = function() {
        alert(myOtherVar);
    };
}


var inst = new Foo;

inst.bar("new value");

inst.baz();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/efqVW/1/

Comment: i was afraid that would have to be it =( i guess this is a flaw of js

Comment: @Garrett: Yeah, the formal parameters in the `bar` function will be closer in the scope chain than the constructor's variables.

Comment: @Garrett: I suppose you could create a private function to set the value, but I'm not sure that's what you'd want.

Comment: nah, just looking for the cleanest code possible. making another function just to set the private member would let me keep the param name, but that's too much of a hassle. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript it is a convention to prefix the name of private variables with an _ (underscore).
Following this convention you can change your code to.

```
function Foo() {
    var _myPrivateBool = false,_myOtherVar;
    this.bar = function(myOtherVar) {
        _myPrivateBool = true;
        _myOtherVar = myOtherVar;
    };
}
```

In the above code we are assigning the local variable myOtherVar to the private variable _myOtherVar.
This way it looks like we have the same name for the private and local variables.

*Note:This is just a convention followed.Prefixing a variable name with _ does not make it a private variable.*

Answer (score -1):

I think this.myOthervar = myOtherVar;   will corrupt the global namespace and created a variable window.myOtherVar in window object

Comment: OP is using the `Foo` as a constructor, so when the constructor is called (as a constructor), `this` will reference the new object being created.

Answer (score -2):

Try `this.myOtherVar = myOtherVar;`

Comment: That sets a property, not a variable.

Comment: doesn't that make it a public member?

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you can declare myOtherVar as MyOtherVar, taking advantage of javascript's case sensitiveness, then assign MyOtherVar=myOtherVar into the function:

```
function Foo() {
    var MyPrivateBool = false,
        MyOtherVar;
    this.bar = function(myOtherVar) {
        MyPrivateBool = true;
        MyOtherVar = myOtherVar;
    };
}
```

Comment: This is a bad practice as Capital case names are for Classes per convention, for example: Object, Date, Math, Person, Vehicle, etc.